# Max number from arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, random, max

I have created a random program with an array with a lot of values and the frequency of each one, inside it, and I would like the program to find the 5 most frequent numbers is there any way I can do that?
`Here is the code I have already written. 2 random arrays, 2 frequencies, find the 5 numbers withe most frequency out of them:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class ArrayElementsAsCounters {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int freq[] = new int[46];
    int freq2[] = new int[21];



    for(int roll=1; roll < 3000000;roll++){
        ++freq[1+rand.nextInt(45)];
        ++freq2[1+rand.nextInt(20)];
    }
    System.out.println("Number\tFrequency");

    for(int number1 =1; number1<freq.length;number1++){
        System.out.println(number1+"\t"+freq[number1]);
    }
    System.out.println("Joker\tFrequency");
    for(int number2 =1; number2<freq2.length;number2++){
        System.out.println(number2+"\t"+freq[number2]);
    }

}
```

}
`

Answer (score 2):

For each value that you have, make them the elements of another array.

This will be the frequency array of the elements.

Now run loop through the original array and each time you encounter an element, add one to its frequency array value.

Then sort the frequency array in descending and starting from the max, print out the first five that are encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MultiSets:

https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html

You can add all elements into the set and do a sort by count afterwards. Given that the question is broad, I'm just giving guidelines, I'll leave the coding part as an exercise for you to do ;)